# .removeChild() not working

Tags: javascript

I had created a form field that can be added, but I can not remove it. Not sure why it is not working, I think maybe I am passing in the wrong parameters? I have tried many variations.

```
<h3 class="color-text">What key fatures are you looking for?</h3>
<p class="contact-message">
    <textarea id="client-needs" placeholder="What key features are you looking to have within your website? ie. storefront, social media intigrtion, a blogging platform, content managment system, ect." name="client-needs" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
function addUrl(){
    if (i<3) {
        i++;
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = '<hr><textarea id="client-needs" placeholder="Add URL #'+i+'" name="client-needs'+i+'" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea><input type="button" value="Remove added URL" onclick="removeUrl(this)">';
        document.getElementById('examples').appendChild(p);

}
}

function removeUrl(textarea){
    document.getElementById('client-needs').removeChild(textarea.parentNode);
    i--;
}
</script>

<h3 class="color-text">Do you have and examples of what you want?</h3>
<p class="contact-message" id="examples">
    <textarea id="examples" placeholder="Do you know of any website like the one you want? ie. google.com, p5services.com, youtube.com" name="examples" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
</p>

<br>

<input type="button" value="Add url example" onclick="addUrl()">
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of `removeChild` is incorrect. To remove added paragrapg with content you should do somethong like this:

```
function removeUrl(textarea) {
    textarea.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(textarea.parentNode);
    i--;
}
```

`textarea.parentNode` is a `p` element to be removed, and `textarea.parentNode.parentNode` is the parent of this paragraph whatever it is. `removeChild` should be called on the parent and it takes a child of the parent to remove.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7caysjw8/

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great and now I will have to read up and make some since of the reasoning, I am amongst quite a learning curve!

Answer (score 1):

id is unique value for each element you got to much same name ID

```
var i = 1;
function addUrl(){
if (i<3) {
    i++;
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = '<hr><textarea id="client-needs'+i+'" placeholder="Add URL #'+i+'" name="client-needs'+i+'" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea><input type="button" value="Remove added URL" onclick="removeUrl('+i+')">';
    document.getElementById('examples').appendChild(p);

}
}

function removeUrl(id){
document.getElementById("client-needs"+id).remove();
i--;
}
```